# How to implement a navigation panel in tree view in Odoo?

Tags: frontend, odoo, odoo-15

I want to implement a side navigation panel like the one in the Chart of Accounts view in Odoo

[image]

I can't find any documentation for this feature, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [searchpanel](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/views.html#search) . By default, it is enabled on the the list view.

To implement it to any tree view, you have just to define the `searchpanel` in the search view.

For chart of accounts, they used the following:

```
<searchpanel class="account_root">
    <field name="root_id" icon="fa-filter" limit="0"/>
</searchpanel>
```